# How to use Cut and Grep command to find data separated by ":"

Tags: grep, cut

In my simple database, it contains text of like, example, soldiers.

```
Name:Rank:Gender:Age:Years of Service

Tom Corporal:Recruit:Male:19:2
Nicole Sergeant:Corporal:Female:30:10
Daniel Recruit:Sergeant:Male:40:19
```

And my script goes like this:

```
echo "Enter name: "
read name

echo "Enter rank: "
read rank

echo "Enter gender: "
read gender

echo "Enter age: "
read age

echo "Enter Years of service: "
read years

grep $name database.txt
```

If I enter "Corporal" into name, the output will show

```
Tom Corporal:Recruit:Male:19:2
Nicole Sergeant:Corporal:Female:30:10
```

because the string matches under the section name and rank.
How do i use delimiter : to categories the search, so if i enter my conditions under rank, it will search just the rank category and not everything else.

Thanks in advance.

And do up my question instead of down voting.

Comment: Do you need to find all the names of a given gender using the `grep` command? Can you better give a sample input and output that you expect so that it would be much more clear?

Comment: you can not use “” quotes you have to use "

Comment: I see nothing wrong except the quotes and that you already know field 3 as that is what you search for. It could also miss trigger, for example I know someone whose name is male, see is female.

Comment: the code does not work, and if i purely use grep $gender Information.txt, it will return all 3 information as in the gender section, it contains "male" and fe"male"

Comment: @Ramesh how else would i be able to do it ?

Comment: lol you guys need to stop complaining about it if it's duplicate or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep "^.*:.*:$gender" Information.txt | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

Comment: this answer will probably be deleted with the question, but that is ok. Welcome!